# content exists, but xpath could not find it, why?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I was using "scrapy shell" to test xpath.
It looked like:

```
scrapy shell https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a219e.1191392.1111.1.FglWUh&id=40978681727&scm=1029.newlist-0.1.50002766&ppath=&sku=&ug=#detail
```

The xpath looked like:

```
response.xpath("//a[@class='shop-name-link']")
```

the result was none, but the page content contains

```
<a class="shop-name-link" href="//shop103857282.taobao.com" target="_blank" 
    data-goldlog-id="/tbwmdd.1.044">长岛小两口创业</a>
```

**Why?**

Comment: Because it doesn't exist.  Look at the source of the linked page; there's no such `a` element.  Create a [mcve] that exhibits the problem, and include a reduced portion on the HTML in your question itself so your question can stand on its own.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems finding results for xpaths use [firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) or chrome browser dev tools to investigate page source. Remember that Scrapy spider sees page source unrendered. It is not rendered with JavaScript. To view source as spider sees it use firepath in browser with JavaScript disabled.

I cannot see link with class `shop-name-link` in page you linked in your question. So either you're not giving proper link or this element is displayed after some user action, or this page is shown in different ways to different users in different countries. It is also possible that page relies on presence of some cookies that you have but we dont have.

There is nice shortcut:

```
 from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
 open_in_browser(response)
```

this will open response from spider in browser. Use it when you need to check what spider exactly sees. In many (if not most cases) this differs from what you see in browser.

If you want to share reproducible example of how you see this page chrome dev tools have useful feature "copy as curl" that will copy request with all headers and cookies to clipboard. If you paste it in your question people will be able to see page as you see it (provided of course there are no geolocation restrictions on ips).